# Description and DetailedDescription attributes of MATLAB classes

Tags: oop, matlab

Built-in MATLAB classes have values for a Description and DetailedDescription attribute:

```
>> ?handle
ans = 
  meta.class handle
  Package: meta

  Properties:
                     Name: 'handle'
              Description: 'Base class for handle classes'
      DetailedDescription: ''
[snip]
```

Similarly, some methods and properties of built-in classes have the same attributes:

```
>> a = ?containers.Map;
>> a.PropertyList(1)
ans = 
  meta.property handle
  Package: meta

  Properties:
                   Name: 'Count'
            Description: 'Number of pairs in the collection'
    DetailedDescription: ''
[snip]
```

How can I set these attributes for my classes/methods/properties?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use arguments to the classdef:

```
classdef (Description='A type of story.',...
    DetailedDescription='Once upon a time..') MyFairyTaleClass
```

Commandline:

```
>> ?MyFairyTaleClass

ans = 

  meta.class handle
  Package: meta

  Properties:
                     Name: 'MyFairyTaleClass'
              Description: 'A type of story.'
      DetailedDescription: 'Once upon a time..'
                   Hidden: 0
                   Sealed: 0
          ConstructOnLoad: 0
         HandleCompatible: 0
          InferiorClasses: {0x1 cell}
```

This is an [undocumented](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/class-attributes.html) feature it seems.

Comment: OK, now I feel dumb for not having actually tried that. Since the Description attribute is underlined red in the editor, I assumed it wouldn't work, but it does - thank you. In case anyone else would like to try this but doesn't want to put up with unwanted and slightly misleading red underlines, you can remove them by adding `%#ok<ATUNK>` after the class definition to hide the "Attribute Unknown" mlint message. This seems to work when defining the attributes for properties and methods as well.