# Which methods keywords (i.e. TestMethodSetup) can occur in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, oop, annotations, custom-attributes

Matlab offers the possibility to declare the type of methods in a methods block by keywords.

The UnitTestingFramework makes use of this ([Example](http://www.mathworks.de/help/matlab/matlab_prog/write-setup-and-teardown-code-using-classes.html)):

```
methods(TestMethodSetup)
    function createFigure(testCase)
        % comment
        testCase.TestFigure = figure;
    end
end
```

I am searching for a complete list of available keywords which are allowed to occure between `methods(` and `)`.

I would like to know this, to be able to contribute to an [issue](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx-contrib/issue/81/matlabdomain-unexpected-attribute-error) in the Spinx-Contrib Matlabdomain.

Comment: You can find list of method attributes for testcases [here](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.testcase-class.html#bt549e6-2)

Comment: If there are no other keywords for non-testcase-related code, this will answer my question.

Comment: From [the doc for method attributes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/method-attributes.html) you can also have: Abstract, Access, Hidden, Sealed and Static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For regular classes, you can have the following documented [attributes for classes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/class-attributes.html):

```
Abstract
AllowedSubclasses
ConstructOnLoad
HandleCompatible
Hidden
InferiorClasses
Sealed
```

for [methods](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/method-attributes.html):

```
Abstract
Access
Hidden
Sealed
Static
```

for [properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/property-attributes.html):

```
AbortSet
Abstract
Access
Constant
Dependent
GetAccess
GetObservable
Hidden
SetAccess
SetObservable
Transient
```

and for [events](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/event-attributes.html):

```
Hidden
ListenAccess
NotifyAccess
```

However the are also some [undocumented attributes](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/undocumented-classdef-attributes) as well - [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13819469/description-and-detaileddescription-attributes-of-matlab-classes) any of the above can also have `Description` and `DetailedDescription` attributes. These get flagged in the MATLAB editor as unknown attributes, but are perfectly usable (and are used by many built-in classes such as `containers.Map`), and the editor flag can be suppressed with `%#ok<ATUNK>`. I use them quite regularly for grouping related methods/properties etc. together.

---

The class [`matlab.unittest.TestCase`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.testcase-class.html#btpx_f8-7) adds class attributes:

```
SharedTestFixtures
```

method attributes:

```
Test
TestMethodsetup
TestMethodTeardown
TestClassSetup
TestClassTeardown
ParameterCombination
```

and property attributes:

```
ClassSetupParameter
MethodSetupParameter
TestParameter
```

---

You don't mention an interest in them, but if you're contributing to Sphinx you might like to also add support for [System Objects](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/matlab.system-class.html#bs4onfj-10), which add property attributes:

```
Nontunable
Logical
PositiveInteger
DiscreteState
```

There may well be more on the way, and more undocumented [attributes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/specifying-attributes.html) right now that I'm not aware of.

Comment: +1 the Parallel Computing Toolbox uses many undocumented attributes, for example check out `edit parallel.Task`: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/setting-class-property-types#comment-191306

Comment: @Amro thanks for adding the links. I wasn't aware of the PCT ones - nice find.

Answer (score 2):

Note these attributes are really just properties of the meta classes, meta properties, meta methods, etc. Observe you can see a list of the valid attributes for a given method (et al) block like so:

```
>> cls = ?matlab.unittest.TestCase

    cls = 

      class with properties:

       SharedTestFixtures: {}
                 TestTags: {}
                     Name: 'matlab.unittest.TestCase'
              Description: 'Class which defines test cases in the MATLAB Unit Test Framework.'
      DetailedDescription: ''
                   Hidden: 0
                   Sealed: 0
                 Abstract: 1
              Enumeration: 0
          ConstructOnLoad: 1
         HandleCompatible: 1
          InferiorClasses: {0x1 cell}
        ContainingPackage: [1x1 meta.package]
             PropertyList: [2x1 meta.property]
               MethodList: [133x1 meta.method]
                EventList: [11x1 meta.event]
    EnumerationMemberList: [0x1 meta.EnumeratedValue]
           SuperclassList: [1x1 meta.class]

>> class(cls)

ans =

matlab.unittest.meta.class

>> method = cls.MethodList.findobj('Name', 'TestCase')

method = 

  method with properties:

                    Test: 0
         TestMethodSetup: 0
      TestMethodTeardown: 0
          TestClassSetup: 0
       TestClassTeardown: 0
    ParameterCombination: ''
                TestTags: {}
                    Name: 'TestCase'
             Description: ''
     DetailedDescription: ''
                  Access: 'protected'
                  Static: 0
                Abstract: 0
                  Sealed: 0
                  Hidden: 0
              InputNames: {0x1 cell}
             OutputNames: {'lhs1'}
           DefiningClass: [1x1 matlab.unittest.meta.class]

>> class(method)

ans =

matlab.unittest.meta.method

>>
```

You can see that these classes that have extra attributes are actually new meta classes which are subclasses of the standard meta classes. That is matlab.unittest.meta.class is a subclass of meta.class and matlab.unittest.meta.method is a subclass of meta.method.

Comment: Hi Andy - is it possible then for a user to create their own subclasses of `meta.class` with new attributes? Can I make, for example, a `sam.meta.class` or a `sam.meta.method`, with a `MyAttr` property? If so, how would I subsequently instantiate a `SamClass` to have the appropriate metaclass, rather than just `meta.class`? Would it be possible for you to add a small example to your answer?

Comment: In particular - would it be possible for me to create classes that have a method (and/or property) attribute `Deprecated`? Would it be possible for the method to fire a warning when called (not from the method itself, but from the meta class, so that the code of the method itself wouldn't need to be changed when deprecated, just the attribute)? And finally, is it possible to get the Code Analyzer to recognize new attributes without a red marker (I know I can use `%#ATUNK` to suppress it, but still).

Comment: Hey Sam, this is not currently accessible from MATLAB code. However, I agree it would be great to do this and it is already captured as a possible future enhancement. I really like your idea of a deprecated attribute!

Comment: I thought you'd say that :( Oh well. Can I give you a couple of other use cases, to add to the enhancement request? Let's say I'm writing a toolbox to distribute, and I want to apply some commercial restrictions to it. I'd like to have a `Compilable=false` attribute, that would be respected by deployment products. And I'd like a `Licensed=true` attribute that would require a license check (against a licensing method that I would implement in a metaclass, um, somehow, waving hands) for the code to be executed, allowing me to provide some code openly and a subset that required a full licence...

Comment: ... (I'd need to p-code everything as well, to stop users just changing the attribute). I know I can do these things using code within methods, but it would be nice to have them as general attributes that could be applied in a uniform way.

Comment: Thanks Sam, use cases captured! Feel free to add any more thoughts or detail that comes along!